# Switch Chart Type. (Dojo)

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

For the moment lets say I have plotted a LineChart with the below code.

```
chart.addPlot("default",{
    type:"Lines",
    markers: true
    tension: 'S',

});
```

How do I swtich the type of the chart in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution which is just rewrite the code and it will be overwritten.